# USB Pendrive doesn't work

Tags: 12.04, usb-drive

I have a Kingston 8GB pendrive, earlier when I connected it to Ubuntu, it was identified by the system. But now when I connect it to Ubuntu the drive isn't identified any longer. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Pls add more details to your poblem.

Comment: Are you able to see it on any other computer?

Answer (score 0):

Open `Disk Utility` and see if you see it there.

If you do, then reformat it from there (FAT) and then mount it.